# How to build a framework for all platforms in single Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, frameworks

Previously to build a framework for particular platform(macOS, iOS), I used to maintain different projects in Xcode and build separately.

My code mostly depends on `sqlite3.h` and a wrapper class written in Swift.

Is there a way to maintain all the frameworks under one xcode project?

I searched but I didn't get any tutorials on the web.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

yes of course xcode can handle this for a long time. you simply create your framework project and then add targets for iOS, macOS, tvOS and watchOS.

[image]
the plus sign below the target pane allows you to add more target. or just duplicate your existing target and change sdk and platform settings.

Comment: It is not just that simple to do. Can you please elaborate your answer with some sample project and steps? Treat him/her like a beginner and try to give an example on how to do it. It will help future readers and beginners. Xcode is a mess for beginners. So please improve your answer. Thank you.